# Indy and TStreams

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy, memorystream

What's the best way to go about sending a TMemoryStream through Indy?

At the moment I'm trying:

```
procedure TClientForm.IdTCPClient1Connected(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(KStore.Size);
  KStore.Position := 0;
  IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(KStore);

  Memo1.Lines.Add('Client connected with server');
end
```

And at the Server end:

```
function MemoryStreamToString(M: TMemoryStream): string;
begin
  SetString(Result, PChar(M.Memory), M.Size div SizeOf(Char));
end;

procedure TClientForm.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  LStore: TMemoryStream;
  Size: Int64;
  LStore := TMemoryStream.Create;
  LStore.Position := 0;
  Size := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadInt64();
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(LStore,Size);
end;
```

But despite a lack of errors, at the other end using that memory stream to string function just returns ???????????????????? in the text file I'm saving it to.

Comment: The best way to send it, is to send it in the way the HTTP server expect it. How the server expect it?

Comment: ? Sorry, I'm not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: How the server expect to receive the stream data? I mean, does the server expect a POST or GET method? in a special param or field name?

Comment: The whole (attempted) server is in the question.

Comment: The server is reading the data into LStore, but after that the LStore goes out of scope.

Comment: You are saying data comes out as question marks, please show that code. If you are sending text, note that unicode conversion might be a source of error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TIdIOHandler.Write(TStream)` and `TIdIOHandler.ReadStream()` can handle the transmission and reception of the `TMemoryStream.Size` property for you, eg:

```
procedure TClientForm.IdTCPClient1Connected(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
  IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.LargeStream := True; 
  IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(KStore, 0, True); 
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Client connected with server'); 
end;
```

.

```
function MemoryStreamToString(M: TMemoryStream): string; 
begin 
  SetString(Result, PChar(M.Memory), M.Size div SizeOf(Char)); 
end; 

procedure TClientForm.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext); 
var 
  LStore: TMemoryStream; 
  S: String;
begin
  LStore := TMemoryStream.Create; 
  try
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.LargeStream := True; 
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(LStore, -1, False); 
    S := MemoryStreamToString(LStore); 
  finally
    LStore.Free;
  end;
end;
```

With that said, you mentioned the error is related to the conversion from `TMemoryStream` to `String`.  Please show what the actual contents of the `TMemoryStream` look like on both ends.  Chances are that the contents are not what you are expecting.  Either the client's `TMemoryStream` contains `'?'` characters to begin with when you stored a `String` into the `TMemoryStream`, or the clien is not sending `UTF-16` encoded characters to the server.